# Query params with DynamoDB Doc Client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, documentclient

I am trying to write params for my DynamoDB Query. I am getting an error and I believe it is from this query.

```
let params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression:
      '(TimeId = :timeId AND begins_with ( TypeKey , :typeKey)) AND (awayTeam = :teamName OR homeTeam = :teamName)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':timeId': `${year}-${week}`,
      ':typeKey': 'GA',
      ':teamName': teamName,
    },
};
```

ERROR MSG: `Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: OR`

```
PK: TimeId
SK: TypeKey
attributes: awayTeam  |  homeTeam
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? year, week and teamName are all defined as path parameters.

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: can you try FilterExpression: '(TimeId = :timeId AND begins_with ( TypeKey , :typeKey)) AND (awayTeam = :teamName OR homeTeam = :teamName)' instead of KeyConditionExpression

Comment: @Nonik I still got an error since a KeyConditionExpression or KeyConditions has to be specified. Going to try a blend of this.

Comment: You use the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter to provide specific values for the partition/sort keys. That means it can only include predicates involving the partition key (an equality test) and sort key attributes (with [limited conditional operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression)).